# Showing ipfw configured pipes

Tags: ipfw

Using **ipfw** I'm configuring pipes, but not actually adding/binding them to a port. For example:

```
ipfw pipe 1 config bw 100KByte/s
ipfw pipe 2 config bw 200KByte/s
```

Above I've configured pipes 1 and 2 if not mistaken. Unfortunately, if I run:

```
ipfw pipe show
```

I get no output. Except if I actually **"ipfw add"** the pipes to a rule, then I can see what their configuration is.

The reason I'm asking this question is I'd like to write a script to create pipes but check to see if there are any pipes already configured so I don't overwrite them with my own pipes.

Comment: Are your kernel and userland on the same build? You should get a list of all pipes from `ipfw pipe show`.

Comment: I think my issue is that I'm trying to "show" pipes that haven't been added, only configured. Running `ipfw pipe show` after something like `ipfw pipe 1 config bw 100KByte/s` produces no output for me until I do something like `ipfw add pipe ...`

EDIT: I'm looking for pre-existing pipe configurations basically. I could very well be doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You first add a rule bound to a pipe then you configure the pipe settings.

You could get a list of ipfw rules that are bound to pipes and derive which pipes exist from that.